# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Lampp Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, lampp

i've installed a server pc in ubuntu with lampp, it's working fine for 2 years, but yesterday i got a report that the server not working like they used to. So i check apache and mysql status, here's what i'v found

[image]

[image]

i've tried to restart apache and it's working, but i'cant start mysql, it says

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

but in Lampp GUI all of this are running

[image]

but Lampp status was like this

[image]

does anyone know what to do? i can access my apps/web but i can't access phpmyadmin, and when i try to login this appear

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sisfo/app/include/function_login.php on line 14
```

same in phpmyadmin

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

EDIT

journalctl -xe output

```
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0  
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0  
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0  
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0  
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x480i"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x576i"x0.0 
Mei 02 03:53:30 BKSERVER /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1416]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 2
```

Comment: What's the output of `journalctl -xe` ? Did you change your MySQL settings or updated MySQL ?

Comment: i added to my question

Comment: i don't know about changing settings, but yesterday i was trying to fix this with solutions i found in internet and try it but still not working, and yeah maybe some settings i've changed

Comment: even i've tried to re-install mysql-server but it won't installing i don't know why

Comment: You need to restart MySQL `systemctl restarts mysql` and right after execute `journalctl -xe`. The journal contains all the most recent logs, on the extracts you've posted it contains only gdm logs which are not relevant to the issue.

Comment: i don't know what jjournalctl is

Comment: and i've tried to restart but still got the same error

Comment: Execute `systemctl restarts mysql` and right after execute `journalctl -xe`. Update your post with the output of the latter.